# Resolve pmd rulesets in Maven locally

Tags: maven-2, pmd

I try do the following:

1. I have a standard POM defined for all my Maven2 projects.
2. That POM includes the tools to use, and for PMD the rulesets to use.
3. I have defined a property that names these rulesets each.

Up to know this is working. I can define a new project POM, use there as parent my standard POM, and use the rulesets there defined. I am even able to override the definition of the property that defines the ruleset by another name.

I have defined that as `auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml` instead of `pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml` (which is then choosen by Maven2) and have included the file `auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml` locally in my new project (under `src/main/resources`). But Maven does not find it. The error messages look like that:

> [DEBUG] Preparing ruleset: auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml
>
> [DEBUG] Before: auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml After: auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml
>
> [DEBUG] The resource 'auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loa
>   der.FileResourceLoader.
>
> [DEBUG] The resource 'auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loa
>   der.JarResourceLoader.
>
> [DEBUG] The resource 'auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loa
>   der.ThreadContextClasspathResourceLoader.
>
> [DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: Exception when looking for 'auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml' at ''
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml

Is there any technique available to reach what I want? I want to redefine the ruleset PMD should use without repeating the whole definition of everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error message, it looks like you may not have specified the full path to your custom rule-set `auth-pmd-rule-set-3.x-v1-5.xml` in your pom.  As per the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html),

> The rule sets may reside in the
>   classpath, filesystem or at a URL. For
>   rule sets that are bundled with the
>   PMD tool, you do not need to specificy
>   the absolute path of the file. It will
>   be resolved by the plugin. But if the
>   rule set is a custom rule set, you
>   need to specify its absolute path.

Comment: Bingo. That was the major obstacle. I'm not sure if the solution is the best one, but it finds now the (changed) configuration file, and uses only that. Thank's a lot!